# Second vim split is not being saved

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I got two files named as vim1 and vim2. vim1 files has some text in it, but vim2 is totaly empty. I used vim vim1 command to open that file. Later on i write :vsplit vim2 to open vim2 file on splited side. I changed my beam to vim2 screen with Ctrl+w command. Later i write this :e vim1 at vim2's split. And i write :wq at this split. After i close the both splits, i checked vim2 file and it was totaly empty. How did this happen?

Comment: Hard to follow. Why would it not be empty? Do you write anything to it?

Comment: :e vim1 does not write while on vim2's split?

Answer (score 1):

Let us look through your sequence of events, with slightly more clear filenames:

- Open `file1` with `vim`.
- (presumably, make edits to `file1`)
- Open `file2` as a vertical split with `:vsp file2`  This puts the cursor into `file2`'s new split.
- Move cursor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> to `file1`'s split.
- Move the cursor with unspecified means back to `file2`'s split.
- Execute the command `:e file1`, which changes the active buffer in what was `file2`'s split to *also* be used to display and edit `file1`
- Execute `:wq` to save and quit `file1`, in the split which had originally been used for `file2`.

At no time was `file2` written to in this chain of events, which is why the file is empty (if it even exists).

Note that at the end of this chain of events, the state of `vim` will be `file2`, as the only remaining open buffer (in what had been the split which was used for `file1`, which was just closed), open in an unsplit interface, as yet unsaved.